# == vs. in operator in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, equals

I had a doubt on comparision operator in python. I would like to know if it's right or wrong.

I have certain output that is assigned to a variable. So let's say:

```
result1, result2, result3
```

Now I do a comparison like

```
if result1 == 0 and result2 == 0 and result3 == 0: 
    print "Success "
else:
    print "failure"
```

My doubt is can this comparison done in this format

```
if 0 in (result1 , result2 ,result3):
    print "Success"
else :
    print "failure"
```

Is this right using Python? If not, then what's the reason?

Comment: It must be obvious that second sample uses is  **OR**

Comment: this "problem" could've been solved by simply trying the code out to see if it works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if 0 in (result1, result2, result3):
```

is equivalent to:

```
if result1==0 or result2==0 or result3==0:
```

What you want is this:

```
if (0,0,0) == (result1, result2, result3):
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
if result1==0 and result2==0 and result3==0:
```

You could actually even do this:

```
if result1==result2==result3==0:
```

since you're checking to see if all 3 variables equal the same thing.

Comment: Python is case-sensitive. So `x OR y` is a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the comparison but your second comparison does not do the same thing as the first.

This comparison will only be `True` when each of the variables is 0:

```
if result1 == 0 and result2 == 0 and result3 == 0:
```

This comparison will be `True` when at least one of the variables is 0:

```
if 0 in (result1, result2, result3):
```

As you can see, that's not quite the same comparison. To perform the same comparison, you can do:

```
if (0, 0, 0) == (result1, result2, result3):
```

Answer (score 3):

In your second example, it will be evaluated to "True" if any of the values is "0", and is not equivalent to `and`.

If you have multiple results and want to confirm if they all match a given value, I suggest using the `all()` function:

```
results = [0, 1, 0]
if all(result == 0 for result in results):
    print "Success"
else:
    print "Failure"
```

or use `any()`

```
if not any(results):
    print "Success"
...
```

However, this inverse logic is often difficult for me to comprehend at first and perhaps it's more pythonic to check for existence than non-existence.  So if you change your logic to check for existence you can just write:

```
if all(results):
    print "Success"
else:
   print "Failure"
```

Comment: Your last example has the logic backwards - either `all(results)` should `print 'Failure'`, or the condition should be `if not any(results):`.

Comment: Thanks, I was implying that the underlying data be changed to check for existence, but it was probably unclear.  I've added your suggestion of if not any().

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps do a variadic function?

```
def allZero(*args):
    for elem in args:
        if elem != 0:
            return False
    return True

if allZero(result1, result2, result3):
    return "Success"
else: 
    return "Failure"
```

Then you can test as many `resultN` at once, as you like.

Comment: voted award for category _"overcomplicated answer for oversimplified question"_ ;)